# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: Problem with dependencies installing MySQL 8.0 server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I'm trying to install MySQL on Ubuntu 18.04. To do that, first I have donwload the package with the command:

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
```

And then, run the command:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
```

But I've got a problem with dependencies and I don't know what are these dependencies. This is part of the message that I've got:

```
Configuring mysql-community-server (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-03-12 01:06:40 CET; 17ms ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 12302 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 12263 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 12302 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"

mar 12 01:06:39 R2D2 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
mar 12 01:06:40 R2D2 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mar 12 01:06:40 R2D2 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 12 01:06:40 R2D2 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-server-dbgsym:
 mysql-community-server-dbgsym depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server-dbgsym (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
 mysql-community-server-dbgsym
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

This is the log that I get consulting with `journalctl -xe`:

```
josecarlos@R2D2:~/Descargas$ journalctl -xe
mar 12 01:35:01 R2D2 CRON[13062]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
mar 12 01:36:01 R2D2 org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1874]: (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:10916): dconf-WARNING **: 01:36:01.2
mar 12 01:36:39 R2D2 sudo[13085]: josecarlos : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/josecarlos/Descargas ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/u
mar 12 01:36:39 R2D2 sudo[13085]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
mar 12 01:36:40 R2D2 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
mar 12 01:36:40 R2D2 audit[13150]: AVC apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile
mar 12 01:36:40 R2D2 kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1552351000.784:89): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_repla
mar 12 01:36:41 R2D2 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mar 12 01:36:41 R2D2 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 12 01:36:41 R2D2 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is RESULT.
mar 12 01:36:41 R2D2 sudo[13085]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

---

Output of `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Hit:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                            
Hit:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                         
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_11.x bionic InRelease                                                               
Hit:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease       
Reading package lists... Done                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
* mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-03-12 12:17:46 CET; 8ms ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 8839 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 8800 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql-8.0/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8839 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "SERVER_BOOTING"

mar 12 12:17:45 R2D2 systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
mar 12 12:17:46 R2D2 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
mar 12 12:17:46 R2D2 systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 12 12:17:46 R2D2 systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-community-server-dbgsym:
 mysql-community-server-dbgsym depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server-dbgsym (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
 mysql-community-server-dbgsym
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---

I have make a big mistake and this is that I've got installed mysql-server-5.5 previously in my laptop. I have remove and purge everything and reinstall again, but it doesn't work.

The log of the command `sudo apt install mysql-server` is:

```
josecarlos@R2D2:~$ LANG=C sudo apt install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-server
  mysql-community-server-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libmecab2 mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-server
  mysql-community-server-core mysql-server
0 upgraded, 11 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 58,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 418 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 libmecab2 amd64 0.996-5 [257 kB]
Get:2 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 mysql-common amd64 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04 [84,4 kB]
Get:3 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mecab-utils amd64 0.996-5 [4.856 B]
Get:4 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mecab-ipadic all 2.7.0-20070801+main-1 [12,1 MB]
Get:5 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 mysql-community-client-core amd64 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04 [1.450 kB]
Get:6 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 mysql-community-client amd64 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04 [2.310 kB]
Get:7 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 mysql-client amd64 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04 [81,0 kB]
Get:8 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 mysql-community-server-core amd64 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04 [17,6 MB]
Get:9 http://es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 mecab-ipadic-utf8 all 2.7.0-20070801+main-1 [3.522 B]
Get:10 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 mysql-community-server amd64 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04 [24,2 MB]
Get:11 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 mysql-server amd64 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04 [81,0 kB]
Fetched 58,3 MB in 2s (30,7 MB/s)       
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 821063 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-mysql-common_8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-client-core.
Preparing to unpack .../01-mysql-community-client-core_8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client-core (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-client.
Preparing to unpack .../02-mysql-community-client_8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-client (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client.
Preparing to unpack .../03-mysql-client_8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmecab2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libmecab2_0.996-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-server-core.
Preparing to unpack .../05-mysql-community-server-core_8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-server-core (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-community-server.
Preparing to unpack .../06-mysql-community-server_8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-community-server (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../07-mecab-utils_0.996-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-utils (0.996-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic.
Preparing to unpack .../08-mecab-ipadic_2.7.0-20070801+main-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic-utf8.
Preparing to unpack .../09-mecab-ipadic-utf8_2.7.0-20070801+main-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../10-mysql-server_8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-common (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-5) ...
Setting up mysql-community-client-core (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-community-server-core (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up mecab-utils (0.996-5) ...
Setting up mysql-community-client (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-1) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27327
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################| 

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-client (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-1) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab.  This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27327
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################| 
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix      : 100% |###########################################| 

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-community-server (8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04) ...
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 installed mysql-community-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 8.0.15-1ubuntu18.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Righ now, these are the package of mysql-server installed in my laptop:

[image]

I don't know what am I doing wrong right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two problems here.

1. `3 not fully installed or removed` error. when you ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. It means that those packages are corrupted. You need to forcefully remove them. Run

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get --force-yes remove mysql-community-server-dbgsym mysql-community-server mysql-server
   ```
2. Now the problem of MySQL not starting. You seem to have upgraded from 14.04 which left some obsolete packages like libmysqlclient18. (Bionic (18.04) has libmysqlclient20)

   Remove all packages related to MySQL and do a "clean installation" of MySQL. Run

   ```
   sudo apt remove --purge libapache2-mod-auth-mysql libmysqlclient18:i386 libmysqlclient18:amd64 mysql-common mysql-community-client mysql-community-client-core mysql-community-server mysql-community-server-core mysql-server
   ```

   Install MySQL again,

   ```
   sudo apt install mysql-server
   ```

Further Reading:

- [How to upgrade to MySQL 8.0? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1122608/816190)
- [How to reset or change the MySQL root password? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16556534/10785056)

Answer (score 17):

This fixed it for me (MySQL 8.0 - Ubuntu 20.04)

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql\* libmysql\*
sudo apt autoremove
```

But the package "**mysql-client-core-8.0**" don't uninstall, so...

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-client-core-8.0
sudo apt-get purge mysql\* libmysql\*
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

No more errors!

Comment: Doesn't apply because the OP is using Ubuntu 18.x and you offer a solution for Ubuntu 20.x.

Comment: The scripts are applicable and functional in 18.04 as well as in previous and later versions.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and tried installing/uninstalling/reinstalling a lot of different packages only to get the same error message repeatedly.

Finally, installing the below MariaDB package (which includes a lot of the same mysql dependencies) fixed my issue.

```
sudo apt install mariadb-client-core-10.3
```